# Не могу опубликовать консольное приложение

Tags: c#, консоль

Всем ку!
не могу опубликовать консольное приложение
при первой попытке публикации я получил ошибку (скриншот 1)
добавил папку FolderForSettingFile
далее при вызове функции которая использует другую папку у меня вылезла аналогичная ошибка, но с другой папкой, посчитал что тупо добавить папку это не решение. Решил спросить у вас, может я как-то не правильно делаю (скорее всего). не ужели нельзя опубликовать приложение таким образом чтобы VS сама учла все относительные пути?[image]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Версию дотнета, тип приложения и код надо угадать?